# Как устроен механизм Remote Method Invocation (удаленный вызов методов)?

Tags: java, методы, rmi

> **Удаленный вызов методов** (Remote Method Invocation - RМI) позволяет создавать на Java прикладные программы, распределяемые на нескольких машинах.

Как устроен механизм работы **удаленного вызова методов** распределенной программы?

Comment: вы именно про RMI хотите узнать? или как строятся распределенные системы?

Comment: вообще интересно как одна программа может быть "размазана" по нескольким машинам, отсюда возник вопрос про методы, посчитав что через них это и происходит.

Comment: это разные вопросы. вы решите, что вам нужно и напишите вопрос.

Comment: ну раз вопрос оформлен выделением RMI, то вопрос оставлю как есть.